# PHP Foreach for single result?

Tags: php, codeigniter, foreach

So in codeigniter I have the following in a model:

```
function get_product_requirements()
{
    $query = $this->db->get_where('settings', array('name' => 'product_laws'));
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

As you could guess this only returns one value. Right now I have a foreach to display this in the browser. It doesn't make sense to me to put a foreach for a single returned value.

```
<?php foreach($laws as $laws){ echo $laws['content']; } ?>
```

Is there an alternative to how I can display this item?

Comment: use "row()" for single result and you can call easily in view

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CodeIgniter's Active Records have a native way of returning one row:

```
return $query->row_array();
```

Then, to access your value, use this:

```
echo $laws['content']; // not inside the foreach loop, of course
```

Read more about different ways to fetch rows here: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html

Comment: I'm getting that `content` is an undefined index?

Comment: Try `var_dump($laws);` to see the whole array. It could be that `content` is missing. How exactly did you call it?

Comment: In my `controller` I have `$data['laws'] = $this->accounts_model->get_product_requirements();`

Comment: And what does the var_dump output?

Comment: The three columns that are in the one row. `id`, `name`, and `content` content being the one I want to echo out.

Comment: I'll write you even a better version for fetching settings, but first you need to tell me the output of var_dump.

Comment: I'll update my question with exactly what it outputs! Actually, just look at this screenshot: http://sellit-now.com/Capture.PNG

Comment: Of course, you don't need to show me the whole `content`, I just need to see the structure of the output.

Comment: just look at this screenshot: sellit-now.com/Capture.PNG

Comment: Hmm, looks like you're still using result_array instead of row_array in your model.

Answer (score -2):

if you sure that you get one row every time you can write your model code in this way:

```
function get_product_requirements()
{
    $query = $this->db->get_where('settings', array('name' => 'product_laws'));
    return $query->row();
}
```

and get your content with:

```
$law = $this->model_name->get_product_requirements();
echo $law['content'];
```

but if you want to stay on your way you can access to your data with

```
$law[0]["content"];
```

reference: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html

Comment: Why would you copy the other two answers?

Comment: i wrote that before you but when i post my answer i see you write something like that. i only want to solve his problem not more!

Comment: And that's why there's a 8-10 minute difference between our answers.